# How to render a pager UI with D365 and over 5000 records

Tags: powerbi, dynamics-365

What’s the process for creating a pager UI when dealing with a large D365 query? It only supports 5000 records at a time, and they have like 50,000 (and counting).

So in order to render the pager for the totals, I’d need to loop though the pager cookies until the end of the resultset and then be able to calculate it? …that can’t be right, can it?

Is there no way to just specify the fetch query and get a count of the total past 5000?

The pager required is the standard

Next 1,2,3…52 Prev

Style of pager